# How to implement error handling in Java 8 when dealing with different kind of errors from different sources?

Tags: java, error-handling, software-design

This question has been asked many times but I couldn't find a satisfying answer.

I am trying to find a way to handle errors in java 8 without limiting too much the shape of the error.

A generic procedure which retrieves data from different sources and produces a result of type T might look like this:

```
T procedure(p) {
    A a = sourceA.get(p);
    B b = sourceB.get(p,a);
    C c = sourceC.get(p,a,b)
    return new T(p,a,b,c);
}
```

All these sources can fail to return a result, so I am trying to find a "general enough" solution to handle the possible errors.

To choose the "strategy" I am focusing on three main non-indipendent concerns:

1. how the error is returned to the caller
2. how the error is handled
3. how much freedom I have in the representation of the error

There are essentially 2 strategies I can think of:

**Result object**.
This is essentially a wrapper object (Result<E,T> or Result<T>) which contains a "response code" and, optionally, a value of type T if everything worked fine.

This solution allows for the error to be returned in a "procedural" fashion

```
Result<T> procedure(p) {
    Result<A> resA = sourceA.get(p);
    if (!resA.isOK())
        return Result.of(resA.getCode())
    A a = resA.getValue();
    Result<B> resB = sourceB.get(p,a);
    if (!resB.isOK())
        return Result.of(resB.getCode())
    B b = resB.getValue();
    Result<C> resC = sourceC.get(p,a,b)
    if (!resC.isOK())
        return Result.of(resC.getCode())
    C c = resC.getValue();
    return Result.of(new T(p,a,b,c));
}
```

or in a "functional" one.

```
Result<T> procedure(p) {
    return sourceA.get(p)
        .flatMap(a -> sourceB.get(p,a)
            .flatMap(b -> sourceC.get(p,a,b)
                .flatMap(c -> Result.of(new T(p,a,b,c))));
}
```

The functional solution is "conceptually" cleaner but a lot harder to read and i think it looks a bit out of place in java. The procedural one looks fine but it's a lot more prone to programming error considering that no one forces you to check the result with isOK before calling getValue/getCode.

Here the handling depends directly on how I choose to represent the error/status.
The simplest solution would be to use an enum. In that case the caller would handle everything with a switch-case

```
Result<T> procedureResult = precedure(p);
if (procedureResult.isOK()){ ...do stuff... }
else {
    switch(procedureResult.getCode()) {
        case CODE1 : ...
        case CODE2 : ...
        ...
        default : ...
    }
}
```

This is a bit limiting because enums are not very customizable. If I need different data for different errors, I have to define one class for each error which would not be a problem if it wasn't for the complexity required to handle the cases.
The only way to handle errors belonging to different classes I can think of is to use what is essentially a visitor pattern and I would like to avoid it.
I am not the only one working on the code and how to use correctly the pattern is something that needs to be learned and I know for a fact no one can be bothered to do it.

A variation on this might be some sort of C-like status:

```
Status precedure(p, resultContainer)
```

Or an "inverted" version of the same idea:

```
Optional<T> precedure(p, statusContainer)
```

But they present the same issues as Result and more.

**Checked Exceptions**.
Here the errors can have whatever shape they want and are easily returned and handled with the famous goto shenanigans.

```
T procedure(p) throws SourceAException1, SourceAException2, SourceBException {
    A a = sourceA.get(p);
    B b = sourceB.get(p,a);
    C c = sourceC.get(p,a,b)
    return new T(p,a,b,c);
}
```

```
try {
    T = procedure(p);
}
catch(SourceAException1 sae1){ ... }
catch(SourceAException2 seae2){ ... }
catch(SourceBException sbe){ ... }
```

On paper this look like the better solution (note that I like the "errors annotations" in the method signature even if it's a bit verbose) but there are 2 problems:

1. in java using exception as an "alternative return" is considered bad practice (by some an anti-pattern even) because an exception signals an exceptional occurrence and should not be used for "expected behaviour".

This might actually be just a matter of preference. What worries me is:

2. the exceptions are slow. From what I found it seems this is caused by the construction of the stack trace.
   In order to alleviate this problem I found out that you can make the stacktrace non-writable but this looks very non-standard and I am not even sure it would make that much of a difference.

So, at the end of all this, my questions are:

1. do you know a better solution to a similar problem which solves some of this issues?
2. Is the checked exceptions with non-writable stacktrace a bad idea?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is how often you expect an _exception_ to take place.  If it's  a common occurrence then I imagine there is an alternate design that could be used.  Additionally, will the exception lead to the program's exit, or, is it utilized as a conditional.

Comment: The question is not exaclty an specific problem. This could end in an opinion based discussion (which I personally like, but this is not the right place). Maybe [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253111/7214091) about "too broad questiosn" could help you. Also, for java 8 you have the library [vavr](https://www.vavr.io/) which offers the [Try class](https://docs.vavr.io/#_try) that if I'm not wrong is doing something similar on what you are asking

Comment: @Reilas i suppose, if used like this, the exceptions would be used frequently. This is why I think in java it would be considered an "abuse" of the exceptions.
But (from a syntactical point of view at least) they look better then the other solutions.

Comment: @GastónSchabas yes I feared the question was going to be be a bit too broad but I didn't know the other websites.
I'll definitly follow your advice and move it somewhere else (softwareengineering looks like the right place).
Should I delete this one or leave it?

Comment: I moved the question to SoftwareEngineering. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/445866/choosing-a-strategy-for-representing-and-handling-errors-or-more-generally-stat